# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug' in Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I can build my project but can not run the app. When executing app it gives me error like

Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.android.multidex.ClassReferenceListBuilder with arguments {/home/Git_Projects/Test1/app/build/intermediates/multi-dex/debug/componentClasses.jar /home/Git_Projects/Test1/app/build/intermediates/transforms/jarMerging/debug/jars/1/1f/combined.jar}

I tried to `clean and rebuild project` and `Invalidate Catche and Restart`. But, nothing helped me.

**build.gradle (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.test1"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://github.com/Kaustubh-Deshmukh/progressbar_repo/raw/master' }

    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/yazeed44/maven' }
    }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.0.1'

    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.5.0'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.kontaktio:sdk:3.3.2'

    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

If I randomly remove some dependencies, then it executes fine. Does large app size creating problem to execute app ?

I am using **android studio 2.3** and **java-8-openjdk-amd64** and **ubuntu 16.04**

One strange thing : Everything was working correct before executing command

```
apt-get update
```

I am searching from days but nothing seems work.

Comment: Did you try `multiDexEnabled true` this option too?

Comment: yes, `multiDexEnabled = true` added already

Comment: @kimkevin you can check in posted build.gradle

Comment: Had the same issue with Android Studio 3.0 but invalidate caches and restart helped.

Comment: Did you add ` MultiDex.install(this)` in Application class for  enable to multidex

Comment: @SagarJethva yes I have added `MultiDex.install(this)` in Application class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After **updating Android Studio** from **2.3.0** to **3.0.1** , my problem solved.

Now, it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

As from your build.gradle file you have two versions for
`compile 'com.android.support:support`

Try using only one of the following:

`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'`
   `compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.0'`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below to build.gradle

```
compileOptions {  
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7  
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7  
}
```

Try to build by command line

```
gradle clean assembleDebug
```

Comment: Have you tried to change gradle version / compileSDK version / buildTool version ?
Sometimes, the latest of their version is a reason of the problem.